# Cannot access internet on host computer when adapter is bridged for a virtual machine

Tags: networking, internet, virtualization, bridge, hyper-v

I am running a Windows Virtual Machine in Hyper-V on Windows 8. To connect the guest machine to the internet, I create a virtual switch using the Hyper-V Virtual Switch Manager. I tell it to use my external WiFi card to connect to the internet. This works fine, and Windows bridges my WiFi adapter and the virtual switch adapter it created.

The guest OS can then access the internet just fine, and it appears on the host machine as though I'm still connected to the WiFi network, but I cannot get internet access *on the host machine*.

So in brief:

I'm connected to WiFi on the host machine

I bridge the WiFi and a Virtual Ethernet Switch (done by Hyper-V).

The guest Machine connects to this Virtual Switch and **can get internet**

The host machine is still connected to the WiFi network but **cannot get internet**

Google searches seem to only turn up results the other way around, where the guest OS can't get internet.

Any tips on resolving is issue?

Much Appreciated!